# Oracle Repository creation utility Unable to connect to oracle 11g Enterprise Edition database DB ORA-01882: timezone region

Tags: oracle

it happened on Oracle fussion middleware error.

Unable to connect to the DB. Check if DB connection details entered are correct. 
   ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

To be very honest, i i've searched thouroughly.

i found out that it had something to do with the jdk in my oracle 11g ee edition so i tried running timezone updater on the jdk, but the timezone was unable to update.. it returned an error saying 'cant rename {0} to {1}'.

am not even sure am on the right path... please can someone out there give me a hand.

Comment: check the docs for RCU and make sure you are using the right JDK. What version of FMW are you using? 11 wants jdk 7, 12 want jdk 8

Comment: its fmw is 12 and i gave it jdk 8.73

Comment: take a look at this on MyOracleSupport: Doc ID 1068063.1, also https://community.oracle.com/thread/2271951?db=5, https://community.oracle.com/thread/2362442?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: thanks for your assistance... it was from my jdk... upgrading from 11g to 12c did the job. i think that upgrade, automatically upgraded the jdk in my oracle.

Comment: but am having a new error..... when am trying to create a domain, and here is what it looks like:                                                                                                 
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher.

Comment: Never seen that error. I've installed 11 and 12 dozens of times on Linux, Unix and Windows and never seen these issues. Perhaps post on oracle fmw community forums and check my oracle support.

Comment: i want to try making the version of jdk in my oracle the same with the version of jdk in my weblogic server

Comment: i've found someone who had my kind of error... here is a link to the site  https://community.oracle.com/thread/3970044

Comment: joe please can you think of any solution to the error? please i need help.

Answer (score 0):

the timezone error was coming up as a result of the character set i selected for my database. it was suppose to be utf8 however, i choose some other one. i had to uninstall my database, and recreated a new one using "utf8" character set, which happens to be a general standard. :)

Comment: Yes, unless you have a specific reason to choose otherwise, *always* choose UTF8 for char set. Glad it's working now.

Comment: but there is new error am now experiencing... when am trying to create a domain, its giving me Error encountered during string decryption. Internal Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher . i think its because am combining the wrong packages. here are my installation files:  oracle 12c database, fmw_12.2.1.1.0_infrastructure.jar and fmw_12.2.1.1.0_wccontent.jar. please am i using the right files.?

Answer (score 0):

Installation of FMW falls into two categories: Developer and Production. Developer uses soa_quickstart + WCC + WCP + MFT etc. WLS and all needed files are installed in this installation and then there are 3 different domains that can be used/configured - local to JDev, standalone (file based no DB or RCU required) and Compact (db required + RCU). Production requires WLS + infrastructure + binaries (SOA/OSB/BPM, MFT, WCC, WCP). These are all separate installs and require DB and RCU as well. So, the question is: what are you installing and why? If you are installing for a production env you should follow the oracle install instructions and [EDG](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/soasuite/SOEDG/title.htm) closely. If you are installing a dev env, then it is very fast and easy - a [standalone env](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/integrated.htm#SOAQS251) is a great choice. While there are some capabilities not available in a Standalone/File- based install, it is still the preferred choice for SOA/OSB/BPM developers. If you simply want a FMW install to play with or use as a developer, you can download and install a [free VirtualBox image](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/soa-vm-2870913.html) that comes fully configure and ready to use. You should also consult the [system compatibility guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html) as well, just to be sure.

Comment: am trying to install oracle web center content and all its ECM features. am also configuring the the domain for production purpose.   i posted a clear and full information about the  error on oracle forums. please visit this link to see it. https://community.oracle.com/message/14021747#14021747   thank you so much.

Comment: i can't get to the link. I've never had those issues and have installed all of this many time son many OSs. Sounds like you have some serious issues in your env. If you are an Oracle customer and having these issues the proper thing to do is log a Support Request with Oracle Support.